# Apache Zeppelin notebook as ipynb

Tags: java, sql, database, mariadb, interpreter

I am using Zeppelin notebook for Mariadb. I exported my work as a ipynb file, then post on in GitHub but it shows "Invalid Notebook
'display_name' is a required property"

I used:
`nbformat v5.9.2` and `nbconvert v7.3.1i triedanu`

I tried many steps using `install converter`.I also uploaded it in a Jupyter Notebook, but the Jupyter Motebook not able to be read.

Comment: So you know, the GitHub view of a Jupyter `.ipynb` is nothing more than mean to be a preview for developers. A lot of features are not supported such as scrolling code horizontally or sharing interactive Plotly plot, etc.. [nbviewer](https://nbviewer.org/') is provided by the Jupyter community and is full-featured. It's renderings are meant to be shared with other stakeholders. There's no guarantee it will work there in your case. **Most likely it will not.** However, it is worth checking out and knowing about for future use. You just put your GitHub link in the form on the page and ...

Comment: <continued> you'll get a page with a URL that points nbviewer at your source `.ipynb` file. Once you examine the URL and determine the pattern, you can make the URLs without even using the form.

Comment: As a solution for your current situation, you may want to open JupyterLab and see if it will convert your file to a better version itself. It is worth trying. It usually will update old formats. I'm not sure about your case yet. You can go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) and click the 'launch binder' badge. After a minute or so the session will open and you'll see the JupyterLab interface. You can drag-and-drop your local `.ipynb` file into the file navigator panel on the left.

Comment: <continued> Once it shows up there, you can double click on it in the file navigator panel and Jupyter should try to open it and it may ask to convert it to fix it. If it fixes it and opens it, save it using the disk icon in Jupyter and then right click on it in the file navigation panel on the left. Then download the fixed version back to your system. (You may want to rename it before this if you are testing things out and want to keep the file before and after separate for now.) If it fixes it, you may want to open it in a text editor and examine the exact changes though they may be ...

Comment: <continued> difficult to detect if you aren't familiar with looking at the json format of the `.ipynb` files.  Using a diff tool may help if you care to pursue that. The idea being it may be easier to do all this fixing by hand in a text editor if the difference is minor. Note that I should have started this second series of comments by saying, "If you want to explore a possible solution for your current situation,...". And if the files still work when you put them somewhere they should run in this form, then you may just have to accept that rendering them in the GitHub preview isn't possible.